# Public Int showing 0 when being used in different Class

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio

I'm trying to set a public int using a button click from a class then using create a new instance and use the value in another class to then be inserted into a DB.

I'm using webforms and C# to produce my system. Any help with this is much appreciated.

CLASS 1 --------------------------------

```
 public partial class Index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        public int ID1;

        public void bLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string username = tbUsername.Text;
            string password = tbPassword.Text;

            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select UsersID from [dbo].[Users] where Username=@uname and Password=@password");
            cmd2.Connection = con;
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", tbUsername.Text);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", tbPassword.Text);

            int Result2 = (int)cmd2.ExecuteScalar();
            ID1 = Result2;

            if (Result > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome");
                MessageBox.Show(ID1.ToString());
                Response.Redirect("Dashboard.aspx");
                con.Close();

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect");
            }

        }

       }
}
```

CLASS 2 -----------------------------------

```
protected void bSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SQLDatabase.DatabaseTable module_table = new SQLDatabase.DatabaseTable("Boards");   // Need to load the table we're going to insert into.

            SQLDatabase.DatabaseRow new_row = module_table.NewRow();    // Create a new based on the format of the rows in this table.


            Index index = new Index();
            string new_id = module_table.GetNextIDBoards().ToString();    // Use this to create a new ID number for this module. This new ID follows on from the last row's ID number.
            string title = tbTitle.Text;
            string body = tbContent.Text;
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            string date = now.GetDateTimeFormats('d')[0];
            string time = now.GetDateTimeFormats('t')[0];

            new_row["BoardsID"] = new_id;                                 // Add some data to the row (using the columns names in the table).
            new_row["Title"] = title;
            new_row["Body"] = body;  // Module name.
            new_row["UsersID"] = index.ID1.ToString();
            new_row["DateCreated"] = date;
            new_row["TimeCreated"] = time;

            module_table.Insert(new_row);                           // Execute the insert - add this new row into the database.

            MessageBox.Show("New Board Created");
            Response.Redirect("Dashboard.aspx");


        }
```

You can see im trying to transfer the ID across classes.

The database insert is fine but its inseting "0" for the ID.

Comment: You understand that each object instance gets a new set of fields, right? The `bSubmit_Click` method creates a brand new instance of `Index` but never calls `bLogin_Click` on it. So it never sets the `ID1` field to anything. The uninitialized value comes back as 0.

Comment: Never store passwords as plain text - they must be salted and hashed.  Also, do not use `AddWithValue`

Comment: Look into storing the ID in the session or somewhere else specific to the user. Static fields exist across all requests, for all users (assuming it's a single server / worker process).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use static field in *Index* class if you want to keep previous value

```
public static int ID1;
```

And this is how you can set its value outside class

```
Index.ID1 = 23;
```

Comment: @early237 Try having multiple users at the same time. This field can only have one value. All logged in users will be using the value of the last logged in user. The new board will belong to the last user that logged in, not the user who pressed the button (unless they're the same user).

Comment: @early237 Please note previous comment by madreflection, static field's value changes for all instances of class

Comment: So how do i make it so more than one user can login/make boards etc? Sessions?? @madreflection

Comment: One way is to store the ID in the session. `Session["ID"] = Result2;` in Index.aspx.cs. Elsewhere, use `int id = (int)Session["ID"];` to retrieve it. But until you assign it, that cast will fail. There's more to it and there are good resources out there, which is why I'm not making it an answer. See `Page`'s [Session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.session) property to start, and read up as much as possible on session management in ASP.NET WebForms.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see this with the code you have provided but it sounds to me based on your description, that you are executing the bLogin_Click method and then creating a new instance of Index.

This new instance will have ID1 have its value default to 0 (unless you set it in a constructor that I can't see). So you need to create the instance first, *then* execute bLogin_Click *on that instance*.

Also looks like you assign a value to Result2, but then perform validation on Result.

Also, not really related but many would consider it bad practice for a class to contain a public field, you should consider using a property instead, even a basic one like this:

`public int ID1 { get; private set; }`

Answer (score 0):

Default Constructor will fires whenever creating a new instance.A constructor without any parameters is called a default constructor; in other words this type of constructor does not take parameters. The drawback of a default constructor is that every instance of the class will be initialized to the same values and it is not possible to initialize each instance of the class to different values.

The default constructor initializes:

**All numeric fields in the class to zero**.
**All string and object fields to null**.

If you want to maintain the state of the type & value to all consumer/client or across multiple instances, just set it as static type.